# force event ('click') in object with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

i have an object that goes like this:

```
let someVariable = {
    ranks: {
        editRank: function(){
            $(".ranking").click(function(){
                console.log('do something');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

all this gets loaded when the page loads. the question is if there is a way of doing something like this:

```
someVariable.ranks['editRank']().trigger('click');
```

i know that this last one doesn't work but that's the behaviour that i'm trying to achieve.

**EDIT**

thanks everybody for taking the time to read and try to understand what i was trying to do, all your comments helped me to find a solution. at the end, the solution was kinda there. the function i had defined in `editRank` was to keep an eye on the click event affecting all the `.ranking` sections, so doing `$(".ranking").trigger('click')` was clicking every active ranking section which was making a mess. luckily i had a `data-rank-id` attribute that i can use, so i did `$(".ranking[data-rank-id='" + rank_id + "']").trigger('click');` and that triggered the function

Comment: `editRank` does not return anything.

Comment: no, just change some things in the page

Comment: Right, but just with that knowledge you should know you cannot chain the logic like that.  So if you *do* want to chain it like that, you have to change something, yeah?  To chain it like that, the method would have to return "something" that you could call trigger on.

Comment: ahhhhhhh, ok, i get your point. i wasn't implying that it has to be done in that way, i was just trying to make my point (goal) clear :P

Comment: @AleVanHoutte `editRank` is just a function which will just register the click event handler to your `.ranking` class. You can call it manually like `someVariable.ranks.editRank()` to register that manually . But then also you need to trigger click event on `.ranking` class by using jquery `trigger()` method . i.e `$(".ranking").trigger('click');` inside  `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Seems like it you want to trigger it, it should be an option with the code that initializes it.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you would need to return the jQuery collection

```
let someVariable = {
    ranks: {
        editRank: function(){
            return $(".ranking").click(function(){
                console.log('do something');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now you will be able to chain it `someVariable.ranks.editRank().trigger('click');`

I think a better option would be to make it option to trigger it

```
let someVariable = {
    ranks: {
        editRank: function(triggerClick){
            const elems = $(".ranking").click(function(){
                console.log('do something');
            });
            if (triggerClick) {
              elems.trigger('click');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and calling it `someVariable.ranks.editRank(true);`

Answer (score -1):

The simplest approach would be to simply encapsulate everything under the .click() as a named function elsewhere in your code, and then just call that function separately, such as:

```
let someVariable = {
    ranks: {
        editRank: function(){
            $(".ranking").click(doClickFunction());
        }
    }
}

function doClickFunction() {
    console.log('do something');
}
```

Then you can just call the named function from wherever else the same steps need to be executed.

Comment: It could work, but if the logic relies on the element reference it will not help.

Comment: That's a good point - but couldn't you just resolve that by passing the element reference to the function?

Answer (score -2):

Use `.click`
I used it for a bookmarlet and it works.

`document.getElementById('element').click();`

It's good for when you want Javascript to click an element instead of the user.